# An Orthogonal Projection with Weighted Norm

Tags: normed-spaces, convex-optimization

In the context of solving a convex program via projected gradient descent i am facing the following problem: 
$$\min_{x\in\mathbb R^2}\lVert x-y\rVert_M^2,\qquad\lVert x\rVert\le1$$
or written equivalently 
$$\min_{x\in\mathbb R^2}\,\langle M(x-y),x-y\rangle,\qquad\lVert x\rVert\le1$$
for a given vector $y\in\mathbb R^2$, where $M\in\mathbb R^{2\times2}$ is a positive definite matrix. While in the case that $M=\mathrm{id}$ the solution is analytical and has the form:

$$
x^*=\frac y{\max\{1,\lVert y\rVert\}}
$$
Is there a closed form solution with the weighted norm variant of this problem i.e. when M is general positive definite matrix?

Mo

Comment: Did you try writing the first order conditions out? The norm is convex and the feasible set of the unit sphere. So solutions to the KKT conditions also solve the problem (I think you can show a constraint qualification fairly easily).

Comment: ps: I'm curious to see how you came up with this problem in the context of gradient descent. Can you elaborate? I feel like I've seen this problem in various forms in various optimization classes but can't recall why. :)

Comment: There is not a closed-form solution, no. But a simple Lagrangian approach should lead to a reasonable numerical method. Make sure to use the squared norm $\|x\|_2^2\leq 1$ as the constraint instead of the non-squared version.

Comment: Let me modify that a little bit. For the $n\times n$ case, there is definitely not a closed-form solution. But perhaps for $2\times 2$, there would be. I wouldn't be surprised if some sort of quartic equation falls out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments guys. 
@ wonko: i am going to look at the KKT conditions. Maybe i can 
substitute some equations into the others.

Comment: The problem by the way arrises from minimizing the dual formulation of the L1 norm. However with a slightly different constraint. 

@ Michael Grant: If an analytical solution doesn't reveal itself, i am going to consider your advice and try to solve it via convex optimization which i would have to do in each iteration of the auxiliary minimization problem.

Comment: I just found a solution for the problem which exactly work as wonky hinted:
ftp://lsec.cc.ac.cn/pub/dyh/papers/ellip.pdf.gz
. See lemma 1 for the key idea.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not seeing a direct application, but if you've worked out it, great! By "numerical method" incidentally, I was not talking about a general convex optimization approach. Rather, I meant a numerical solution to the KKT equations. Form the Lagrangian, differentiate w.r.t. $x$ to get one of KKT conditions (the others being $\lambda\geq 0$ and $\|x\|_2=1$), and solve numerically.

Comment: Thank you Michael Grant, now i get what you said. This is exactly what is done in the paper I've attached above. Lemma 1 tackles the KKT conditions
and calculates an analytical solution.